# Is there a way to put "req.getParameter" inside a "for loop" so it saves in database depending on the x amount a user gives in another servlet?

Tags: java, variables, servlets, request, html

I'm developing a system in which a teacher can edit the exam he/she has previously created, but the problem is that saving the questions and answers depend on how many question the exam has.

When I request variables from the "editing servlet" to the "saving servlet" I cant find a way where I can create String variables for every question&answer so they can be saved into mySQL database.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String numpreguntas = req.getParameter("x");
    int Nump = Integer.parseInt(numpreguntas);
    String numrespuestas = req.getParameter("y");
    int Numr = Integer.parseInt(numrespuestas);
    String nombre = req.getParameter("strNombre");

    for(int i=1; i<Nump; i++) {
        String resp = req.getParameter("answeri-j");
    }

    actualizarBD(nombre, Nump, Numr, resp);
    devolverPaginaHTML(res, nombre);

}
```

Comment: How do you compose the name of the answer parameters (some like answer1-1)? Also, do you want to concat all the answer values, or save every answer independently?

Comment: all the answer values. Yes I do save them in the past servlet as answer1/1 *like answer 1 from question 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ServletRequest getParameterMap will give you all the parameters and values passed on the request. You can then use this to iterate over rather than look for individual parameters.